# Sphinx autosummary does not use labels in toctree

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

Is there any option to use labels in sphinx-autosummary toctree?
Sphinx can build a toctree such as:

```
.. toctree::

  Main page <module.main>
```

The above will display "Main page" in the TOC of the HTML document.
I would like the same using autosummary toctree

```
.. autosummary::
  :toctree:
  
  Main page <module.main>
```

However, the above label produces: *module\main.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree*

The purpose of this, when the html page is generated the TOC shows:

```
module package
   module.main module
```

What I want to see is:

```
module package
   main module
```

I am not even sure that this is the right place to achieve the above rendering

Comment: If you try just `module.main`, do you get the same warning? Also to which file does the warning refer? Usually it pertains to `.rst` files, not Python (or whatever language) modules.

Comment: For autosummary toctree, when I use module.main it works. Please see the updated explanation.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing the `.. toctree::` *directive* and the `:toctree:` *option*. The entries of a `.. toctree::` directive are names of RST files. The entries of an `.. autosummary::` directive are names of Python objects (classes, functions). The `:toctree:` option on `autosummary` takes one argument: the name of the directory where Sphinx saves autogenerated RST files. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27350467/407651.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out where this whole issues is coming from. The cause isn't in the toctree but the titles of each rst file. I use apidoc and autosummary.
The apidoc has a template pacakge.rst that builds a toctree and it uses the titles of the generated .rst files to display the name in the *.html.

By title I mean, if you open the autosummary/module.rst:

{{ fullname | escape | underline }}